# can someone help me with my activity diagram i think it too hard to draw when i draw activity diagram

Tags: android-activity, diagram

1. Customers enter the store
2. The staff greets customers and leads them to the shopping area
3. Customer selects the item to buy. During the selection process, the customer can ask the staff about the product, the staff will look up information on the system to answer the customer. When choosing the items to buy, customers can dictionary or ask the staff to fill in the items they need to buy in the voucher.
4. Customers come to the checkout counter. The cashier receives the purchase slip and enters the invoice into the system. The staff collects the money from the customer and then prints the invoice for the customer.
   5 customers receive goods at the warehouse. Customers come to the warehouse, the warehouse manager receives the invoice from the customer and checks it on the system
   6 customers receive the goods and leave
   Can someone help me to draw a diagram for this. i don't understand hơ to draw it

i try  draw 2 time but i can draw when customer choose goods , can someonehelp me

Comment: Hi. Can you show us what you already have? Maybe we can help from there...